# Getting ios build error while building for device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-m1

This is the error that i am currently facing.

```
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
Recovery Suggestion: Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built.
```

And this error started appearing after i have added the info.plist file.

Comment: Can you check your info.plist and buildsettings/packages/info.plist file/ directory
and check the product identifier etc, can you give more details about that